# Having trouble dividing lengths with calc package

Tags: calculations, scaling

What I want is something like `\resizebox` but which I can give a maximum height and width to, it will make it fit into those bounds, and not distort the image. (`\resizebox`, of course, always makes it fit the exact size you give it unless you use `!`. If you *do* use `!`, you have to settle on whether you want to set the height or width dimension.)

So I'm trying to write one, but I'm having problems with the `\ratio` command from the `calc` package. Whenever I use `\ratio`, I get "Missing number, please try again."

What am I doing wrong? (If you have any better suggestions for my original problem, I'm open to those too, of course.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{settobox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\newsavebox{\theCurrentImage}
\newlength{\theCurrentImageHeight}
\newlength{\theCurrentImageWidth}
\newlength{\heightIfWidthExpanded}
\newlength{\widthIfHeightExpanded}

\newrobustcmd{\image}[1]{%
  \sbox{\theCurrentImage}{#1}%
  \settoboxheight{\theCurrentImageHeight}{\theCurrentImage}%
  \settoboxwidth{\theCurrentImageWidth}{\theCurrentImage}%
  % If the aspect ratio of the image is wider than the aspect ratio of the
  % screen, we are limited by the text width. Otherwise, we are limited by
  % the text height.
  Image width: \the\theCurrentImageWidth  \\
  Image height: \the\theCurrentImageHeight  \\
  Text width: \the\textwidth  \\
  Text height: \the\textheight  \\
  \ifnumcomp{\ratio{1pt}{1pt}} %\ratio{\theCurrentImageWidth}{\theCurrentImageHeight}
            {>}{\ratio{1pt}{1pt}} %\ratio{\textwidth}{\textheight}
            {% Width limited
              Width limited \\
              \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\theCurrentImage}}%
            }%
            {% Height limited
              Height limited \\
              \resizebox{!}{\textheight}{\usebox{\theCurrentImage}}%
            }%
}

\begin{document}

\image{Hello world!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A good practices are 1) Do not resize images, and 2) Make the images only of a certain predefined sizes. When you resize vector image line thickness changes. Having 10 images of 10 different sizes isn't a good typography.

Comment: Given the choice between go with "poor typography" or "spend the next two weeks manually creating the images" I'll go with the former.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ian's answer pointed me into the right direction: This is easily possible with the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox) package by Martin Scharrer. It basically gives you an `\includegraphics`-like interface to be used with any (boxable) material:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

  \adjustbox{width=400pt,height=800pt,keepaspectratio=true}{Hello, World}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `adjustbox` package. Looks useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked like a charm. (Too bad it's not apparently included in texlive 2010, but whatever.)

Comment: @EvanED: Note that there is also an `adjustbox` environment which would be better suited around a `tikzpicture` environment. However, `\adjustbox` doesn't mind when the `{ .. }` are replaced by `\bgroup .. \egroup`, so it could also be split between the begin and end of a custom environment.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `\includegraphics`, you can specify height, width and whether you wish to preserve the aspect ratio. With the option `keepaspectratio=true`, the image will be made as large as possible, whilst not exceeding the specified height or width.

```
\includegraphics[width=400pt,height=800pt,keepaspectratio=true]{myfile}
```

For details of the options accepted by `\includegraphics`, see section 7.5 of [epslatex.pdf](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf).

More generally, you could make two boxes:

- the original object, scaled so that its width is the total width available,
- the original object, scaled so that its height is the total height available.

The box that you want will always be the smaller of these two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myscale}[1]{%
\newbox\bigbox
\newbox\anotherbigbox
\sbox\bigbox{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{#1}}%
\sbox\anotherbigbox{\resizebox{!}{\textheight}{#1}}%
\newdimen\bigboxwidth
\newdimen\anotherbigboxwidth
\bigboxwidth=\wd\bigbox
\anotherbigboxwidth=\wd\anotherbigbox
\ifnum\bigboxwidth<\anotherbigboxwidth\usebox\bigbox\else\usebox\anotherbigbox\fi
}%
\begin{document}
\noindent
\myscale{\rule{10pt}{1pt}}
\newpage
\myscale{\rule{1pt}{10pt}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not using includegraphics. (Despite the name of the macro. Instead, it's pgf/tikz code generated by dot2tex.)

Comment: @EvanED --- Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I have edited my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks for the edit... I didn't try this out, but it'd probably work. Daniel's sounds more robust though.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using my `adjustbox` package already mentioned in the accepted answer of Daniel, you also can use an internal if-switch to make `\resizebox` do the work for you. The `keepaspectratio` option of `\includegraphics` (which comes from the same package as `\resizebox`, `graphicx`) simply set the `Gin@iso` switch to true. There is no public interface for this for `\resizebox`, but you can use `\Gin@isotrue` to set it locally, either between `\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother`, or using `\csname Gin@isotrue\endcsname`:

```
{\csname Gin@isotrue\endcsname
 \resizebox{<height>}{<width>}{<content>}}
```

This is identical to using `height=<height>,width=<width>,keepaspectratio` with either `\includegraphics`, `\adjustbox` or `{adjustbox}`. However, the last two process the content as box not as macro argument and therefore allow for verbatim content.